# Grep and make new data frame from these values

Tags: r

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
10 20 30 10 20 30
 1  2  3  4  5  6
 3  4  5  3  7  8
```

where the first row `(10, 20, 30..)` are headers

I want to create a table with just values from columns whose name is `"10"` like this:

```
10 10
 1  4
 3  3
```

Comment: This is just an example, I would have way more columns than just those two

Comment: `df[,grepl("10",colnames(df))]` ?

Answer (score 0):

As @digEmAll suggested:

```r
df[, grepl("10", colnames(df))]
  10 10.1
1  1    4
2  3    3
```

`grepl` returns a logical vector reporting if the string `"10"` is found in each column name in `df`. We then use square bracket notation to select only those columns where the condition is `TRUE`.

You should know that it's bad form to have identical variable names and R often does weird things with them (for example, renaming the second `"10"` column `"10.1"`).